# RSNNS package with separate training and test

Tags: r, neural-network

So I have already separate training set and test set such that each row is a row has of unique data split in each column (microarray values) of data and the last column is the class (0 or 1).

I have used the iris example to get my dataset identical to how it gets loaded in, but every example I see uses splitForTrainingAndTest function to split a data set to training and test. But What if in my case, they are already separate?

Answer (score 0):

If you read carefully the examples provided in [RSNNS:Examples](http://dicits.ugr.es/software/RSNNS/index.php?view=Examples%20of%20high-level%20API) then you will realise that the final command should look like

```
model <-  mlp(your_inputs_training, your_targets_training, size = 5, 
  +      learnFuncParams = c(0.1), maxit = 60, inputsTest = your_inputs_crossval, 
  +      targetsTest = your_inputs_crossval)
```